# If a wireless router sends packets all by broadcast and with its full bandwidth, can each connected device receive the same full bandwidth?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, broadcast

If a wireless router sends packets all by broadcast and with its full bandwidth, can each connected device receive the same full bandwidth?

The possible scenario is like this:

1) connect one device to a wireless router to its wired port, and then send broadcast packets, let's say 100Mb/sec.

2) if the wireless router send these broadcast packets by wireless to other devices, can each device receive packets at the same 100Mb/sec speed?

This is actually intended to duplicate one packet to many.

Comment: No; because the wireless network has throughout limits also.

Comment: But it is broadcast, the router does not have to send the packet to each device one by one. I just want to make sure of it.

Comment: You don't have a 100MB/sec wireless network I guarantee you that.  I will repeat, the wireless network has a limit on its throughput, each client CANNOT each download at the same speed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Yes the router does (can) broadcast SSID. No the router (or the cheap ones I use) can Broadcast (stream) the same packet to multiple devices without overhead (like said above).

There was a article recently about significant improvements in switching in regards to WiFi. I can't remember where I read it.

Last place I worked that had true Wireless broadcast was using satellite. Where one packet was sent to the satellite and then broadcasted out for all that listened. Fun but a little slow at the time and lots of pricey dedicated hardware.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it does have overhead. I just want to make sure it is in a broadcast manner, but not a one by one manner. If each device can get a 50Mb/sec bandwidth in my example, if I connect 10 devices, that is still 500Mb/sec total throughput. Am I right?

Comment: Minus packet overhead, signal interference, quality of the router, switching. Basically in my study I have never got that sort of magic.Think of this: The Cable company says I'm on a 50Mbps service. Am I going to get that ;) Heck no lol. I would say the other problem is the receiving side. I could be wrong. Been wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

A Wi-Fi broadcast or multicast will always be sent at the lowest available wireless speed.
This allows for every device to be able to hear it. The reason is that if your device is far from the AP it will be using a more robust coding rate and modulation to improve goodput (say BPSK). So, you device will not be able to hear the packet if the AP sends the broadcast/multicast packet at a higher rate (say 64QAM).
You should be able to configure your WIFI system to send broadcasts at higher minimum rates, but you will reduce the reachability of your overall WiFi system.
Regards,
Celso